# Combining Bootsrap controls with Razor HTML helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

My first time ever learning and doing **ANY** web development, so it might look like an obvious question but my confusion is this:
In my **MVC** app at first I started using controls from examples of `Twitter Bootstrap` site so for example a drop down looked all pretty and nice then I learned that I want to use for example `@HTML.CheckBoxFor`, etc. in my **Razor** code so used that, now the controls look ugly and just like their plain HTML definition looks. 
So my question is how can I keep using `@HTML` helper for my controls and model binding in Razor while keeping the look and flexibility of their `Bootstrap` controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your property is of type `bool` then try this for a checkbox:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.property1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.property1)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.property1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the `checkbox` class name is from bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

All of the HTML helpers have an overload that allows you to pass in an object hash that get converted to HTML Attributes.

You can use that to add classes to your control:

```
@Html.CheckBox("Blah", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: oh so that's the secret ? passing  @class = "form-control" would remind them that hey render it like a boostrap control?

Comment: @Bohn - It's not really a reminder, you are literally telling it to render an `input` control of type `checkbox` with an attribute `class="form-control"`

All you need to do now is make sure you have all the appropriate markup and classes to match what bootstrap wants and you should get the appropriate visual styles.

Comment: @Bohn - If you look at the answer BviLLe_Kid provided, you will see basically the full markup needed to get what you want. At the end of the day, all the HTML helper does is render some markup with the appropriate conventions needed to make sure all the model binding is happy.

Comment: Thanks for explanations :)